# Silverlight and Flash goes out of app frame

Tags: facebook, silverlight

I have two apps on page tabs on my fan page, one is written in Silverlight and second one is made in Flash both has same problem when I scroll down they are going out of app place (frame or whatever).

I think screenshots will tell you all about the problem.

things that ive tried before posting this question:

1) [css] z-index;

2) [html] place Silverlight and Flash (object tags) in iframe;

3) and tons of Google search results

```
<div id="silverlightControlHoster"> <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="520" height="292">
<param name="source" value="galaxy.xap"/>
<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="background" value="white" />
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="false" />
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
<img src="slerror.png" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
</a>
</object>
<iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
</div>
```

and CSS for "silverlightControlHoster"

```
#silverlightControlHoster {
display:block;
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:145px;
text-align:center;
height:292px;
width:520px;
```

### Screenshot of Silverlight:

[image: Screenshot of Silverlight]

### Screenshot of Flash:

[image: Screenshot of Flash]

edited: I solved it myself
the problem was property "windowless" in object tag
if you are viewing Silverlight in window (such as facebook page tab) you must add these properties
just copy and paste it between object tags :)

```
<param name="background" value="transparent" />
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
```

and for flash:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

Comment: Did you check app settings in facebook developers page? there are some options about scroll/iframes in that page